# Bootstrap 4 + Isotope

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-isotope

I have a simple project. I use isotope for masonry grid and Bootstrap 4 (`flex`):

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

    function gridMasonry(){
        var grid = $(".grid")
        if( grid.length ){
            
          grid.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            masonry: {
              //columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
            }
          });
            
        }
    }
    gridMasonry();
});
```

```css
.grid-item img {
  height: 192px;
  width: 100%;
  
  object-fit:cover;
}

.y-2.grid-item img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row grid">
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x900/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=img" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="grid-sizer col-4"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Try and `grid-sizer` but the blocks still "jump". **Last `col-sm-4` not correct**.

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................... ..................... .....................

**Question:** How to combine bootstrap 4 columns of different widths (col-) and different height and Isotope masonry grid?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to use layoutMode `fitRows` instead...

```
   grid.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
   });
```

https://codeply.com/go/zNeDtV9nLE

---

Also note that you must import the other `layoutModes` separately. It looks like you'll need to play with the other layoutModes ('packery', 'masonry') to see which works best. I'd also use `d-block` on the row to disable flexbox.

https://codeply.com/go/BB7IVChoXc

Comment: And if different height for col-

Comment: Please add different height images to the example

Comment: Actually your images aren't wide enough to see that the columns are filling the correct width: https://www.codeply.com/go/BB7IVChoXc

Comment: Isotope was breaking the Bootstrap v4 grid until I moved the Isotope container selector to the same element that has the `.row` class. If you see items in your grid wrap unexpectedly after adding Isotope, try this.